# Django server fails to start in webbrowser

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a Django Project, using PayCharm. Here what I get:
[image]

And when I klick on the Link, I see the following:
[image]

How can I resolve this Problem?

Update

I have checked my urls.py and that is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: what problem? you get a 200 success response

Comment: Check your urls.py, what view handles response to root /?

Comment: A Django start up page should appear in Browser, but I see nothing

Comment: keep DEBUG = True and check it again please

Comment: DEBUG is already True